# Result set usage when expected one int value only

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I know it is basics and probably really simple, but I'm struggling with the following situation where i want to query the database for a specific int(id in my case), but somehow i can't acces the returned data from the data set.

I have tested the query in db managment system and it works. I get no errors/ stacks but the result of my method is always -1.(Which means it fails :( because no int has been parsed)

code:

```
public int UserFactoryEngine(String n, String p){
        // query for user data, validate and return
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Failure intialization of the driver! ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" + "databaseName=BugsSurveillance;user=sa;password=1234;integratedSecurity=true;";
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Failure intialization of the connection! ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Connected... ");

        String sqlquery;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
        ResultSet rs;
        try {
            preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM Users WHERE name = ?  AND pass = ? ",
                    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,  ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, n);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, p);
            rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Prepared statement failure!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Your method is always returning -1. What is the output of `System.out.println(rs.getInt(1))?`

Comment: nada, no print no nothing... :( it is like nothing is returned and i suppose the sys out wont print anything, not even new line :s

Comment: It means that your program doesn't enter in the `while()` loop. Do you have records in your table?

Comment: yes, told you i have tested the query in the ms managment system. Well and why would it not enter the loop?:\

Comment: Commonly because `ResultSet.next()` is false, meaning you don't have records.

Comment: then what am i doing wrong? the query is testes with `SELECT id FROM Users WHERE name = 'foo' AND pass = 'bar' ` and it returns one instance, but in java it fails... any ideas?

Comment: Are you passing the parameters of the method in the correct way? I mean `UserFactoryEngine("foo", "bar")` instead of `UserFactoryEngine("'foo'", "'bar'")`

Comment: I suppose that i does not mather, as long as you use a java string with method setString it will set a string to a DB format meaning '' brackets..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering this is a login factory(what i'm trying to implement) i have been using a JPasswordField, which it seems needs a bit more atention when it comes to the getPassword() method. So because of that I wasen't able to succesfully find some matching string in database.

Fix: used JTextfield with hidden characters.

Comment: Or you could use `String pass = new String(jPasswordField.getPassword())`. That works for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting any output to the console from the

```
while (rs.next()){
    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
}
```

because there are no results. Initially the ResultSet is pointed before the first row. When next() is called, it increments to the next row, and returns true only if the new current row is valid, which it must not be in this case.

Since you say the row exists, try replacing your lines

```
preparedStatement.setString(1, n);
preparedStatement.setString(2, p);
```

with hard coded values, for testing. So, if your username is admin, and your password is 1234.

```
preparedStatement.setString(1, "admin");
preparedStatement.setString(2, "1234");
```

Another test you could try is to

```
SELECT * FROM users
```

and see if you get any results that way.

Comment: yep i do, so do i get  something with `Select * from Users` and i do get something from `Select * from Users WHERE name=?` where setString(1,p)